# Equilibrium Condition For Kelvin's Equation regarding "Equilibrium Vapour Pressure and Curvature of Drops"

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, equilibrium, surface-tension

This is regarding the Correction due to 'Curvature of the drop' made by Lord Kelvin to the Clausius-Clapeyron Equation.

So, the idea is that, during large scale nucleation of water vapour into cloud droplets, the equilibrium vapour pressure over a droplet of radius r, is given by
$$e_s^{\ curved}(r) = e_s(\infty)*e^{\frac{2\sigma}{\rho_w R_vTr}}$$
where, T = temperature, $R_v$ is gas constant for water vapour, $\rho_w$ is density of drop, $\sigma$ is Surface tension, and $e_s(\infty)$ is the equilibrium vapour pressure over a plain surface at temp T.

In order to derive this equation, we used the Gibbs Free Energy, and calculated that for this drop formation process, $\Delta G = - R_v T ln(\frac{e}{e_s}) \rho_w \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 + \sigma 4 \pi r^2$

Now, when $e>e_s$, then the graph of **$\Delta G$** vs r, initially increases up to a critical radius R and then decreases as shown ($S = \frac{e}{e_s}$):

[[image: The Curve for <span class=]$\Delta G$ vs r, S=e/e_s" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTVxb.png)

Then, to find the equilibrium condition, we said that *The drop is in equilibrium with the surrounding when the radius = R, since the slope of $\Delta G$ wrt r is $0$ at r = R*

However, I feel that the equilibrium condition arises for the radius r, for which, $\Delta G = 0$. This interpretation doesn't affect the final formula much. It just replaces the "2" with a "3". But, I am concerned about the interpretation.

Q: Which one of these interpretations is correct and why? Why is the other interpretation incorrect?

[Kelvin's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_equation), and
[A sample Derivation](https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Kelvin2.htm#:%7E:text=%3D%20RwT.ln) - Similar derivation is in the book "Atmospheric Science - by Wallace and Hobbs"

Comment: What is the meaning of $\Delta G$? Which two states does it compare? What does $\Delta G = 0$ mean for those two states?

Comment: @JánLalinský, $\Delta G$ refers to the change in Gibbs Free Energy.The Initial state, was of the ambient atmosphere with water vapour, and the final state is after the water droplet was formed in the atmosphere. So, if I am correct in my interpretation, $\Delta G = 0$ indicates that the drop is in equilibrium with its atmosphere.

Comment: OK but I have a problem with the last sentence. Why would condition of equilibrium (your $\Delta G = 0$) compare two very distant states: 1) vapor without liquid drop 2) vapor with liquid drop large enough to be stable (smaller droplets will spontaneously disintegrate)? Shouldn't condition of equilibrium compare two infinitesimally close states? By random fluctuations, a stable drop can slightly decrease or increase its radius, so the condition of equilibrium should reflect changes of $G$ when changing between those close states.